# Is it possible to put java 1.4 on 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, jdk1.4

I need to set up a legacy app that uses Tomcat 4 and runs using the 1.4 JDK.

I tried to install the linux JDK 1.4 from the sun download site on Ubuntu 9.04 but it wouldnt install.

Is it possible to install JDK 1.4 on the 64 bit version of Ubuntu?

When I try and install the j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64.bin version i get the following error

`./install.sfx.22146: 1: ��: not found

./install.sfx.22146: 1: ELF2�@@H�@8@@@@@@����@�@@@��������P: not found

./install.sfx.22146: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Have you tried running the app on a newer version of the JDK to see if it would work?

Comment: Yes works fine in newer JVM but will have to deploy app on legacy server, with tomcat 4 JDK 1.4

Comment: Exactly which download did you use (provide link)?   For Ubuntu you need the tar-distribution (if I recall correctly).

Comment: I tried to install the j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64.bin, but came up with an error

./install.sfx.22146: 1: ��: not found
./install.sfx.22146: 1: ELF2�@@H�@8@@@@@@����@�@@@��������P: not found
./install.sfx.22146: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you particular about 64bit Java 1.4 ?
I have tried with 32 bit Java 1.4 and it works.
I clustered the web app to make use of more than 2GB memory.

Answer (score 0):

SAP is paying extra to get just such a setup [supported](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/01/16/sap_sun_java_netweaver_support/), so I assume that there is no technical limitation preventing it.  However, there may be licensing restrictions preventing it.

However, I'd recommend running it on a later JDK if possible.  Just because the code was compiled for an earlier version doesn't mean it won't run on the more recent JRE.

Comment: oh welll, doesnt look likely then. Just trying to duplicate the live environmnet, just neeed to use my windows vm then!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32-bit libraries installed, you can run a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit Linux no problem (except of course the maximum process size is limited due to being 32-bit). You don't need a VM, and possibly not even a chroot. At least in Debian, there are ia32-libs packages that contain a 32-bit libc and a few other libraries, and you don't need a lot of shared libraries just to run the JVM.

`j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64.bin` is for IA64, not AMD64 (x86_64)- they're completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is launched in an incorrect manner. The ELF string indicates an executable, but it's being launched as a shell script, i.e. `sh xxxx.bin` instead if `./xxxx.bin`;

Answer (score -1):

yeah 32 bit binaries are not going to work on a 64 bit system.  You can put a 32 bit vm on the 64 bit ubuntu server (vmware player?) .  Then run tomcat inside of that.